# Why can't I cast base reference to a variant interface implemented by derived class?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following interface and classes:

```
private interface ITest<in T1, out T2>
{
}

private class TestClass
{
}

private class TestClass<T1, T2> : TestClass, ITest<T1, T2>
{
}
```

With these, I can do:

```
    TestClass testBase = new TestClass<Parent, Child> ();

    TestClass<Parent, Child> testGeneric = (TestClass<Parent, Child>)testBase; // Works fine
    ITest<Parent, Parent> testInterface = (ITest<Parent, Parent>)testGeneric; // Works fine
```

But if I try to combine the two, I can't do:

```
    ITest<Parent, Parent> testInterface = (ITest<Parent, Parent>)testBase; // Fail!
```

Why can't I just cast directly here? Is this just a limitation of C# casting or variant interfaces?

If the type parameters of the interface match the types of the generic class exactly, it actually works:

```
    ITest<Parent, Child> testInterfaceExact = (ITest<Parent, Child>)testBase; // Works
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works fine here and [on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sSLQ3I). Please provide a [mcve] and mention the compiler version you are using.

Comment: I'd expect this to work, is `Child` actually a subtype of `Parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `TestClass` is really not `ITest<T1, T2>`. It is not related to the interface and therefore you cannot just write:

```
(ITest<T1, T2>)new TestClass();
```

On the other hand, non-generic `TestClass` is related to the generic one as its base. Therefore, the following instruction is actually a downcast:

```
(TestClass<T1, T2>)new TestClass();  // will fail at run time...
```

Downcast may succeed or fail at run time, depending whether actual object is of the derived type or not. Compiling that will always succeed.

Now if you wanted to have base reference to the derived object, that is fine. But if you wish to convert that to anything known to derived class only, such as your interface, you will have to perform the downcast first:

```
TestClass derived = new TestClass<T1, T2>();
ITest<T1, T2> interf = (TestClass<T1, T2>)derived;
```

You don't even have to cast to the interface, because generic class already implements that interface.

The issue is getting worse with variant type arguments. Compiler cannot check whether the cast is possible if it doesn't have access to variance information of generic arguments. Once you cast to the generic class, compiler will be able to infer variance correctly and to assign the reference:

```
TestClass derived = new TestClass<Parent, Child>();
ITest<Parent, Parent> interf = (TestClass<Parent, Child>)derived;
```

The fact that your last line works, and that is:

```
ITest<Parent, Child> testInterfaceExact = (ITest<Parent, Child>)testBase;
```

is only because you haven't changed generic types and therefore compiler didn't have to infer variance information (which it doesn't have) at this line.